# Buscar datos de un txt en array y actualizar

Tags: php, array, parsear

Estoy realizando un código sencillito pero no consigo sacarlo adelante a ver si pudieran echarme una mano por favor.

Tengo un archivo `.txt` que me presenta los siguientes datos:

```
id|tipo|contador    
id1|0|1
id2|0|1
id1|0|2
...
id20|0|1
id2|0|2
etc...
```

Código/idea que uso pero no está terminado, faltan bucles etc.:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

    $text = file_get_contents('C:\users.txt');
    $exploded = multiexplode(array("|"," ","\n"),$text);

    $id[i] = trim($exploded[0]);
    $type[i] = $exploded[1];
    $count[i] = $exploded[2];
$datos[] = array('id'=>$id[i],'tipo'=>$type[i],'contador'=>$count[i]);
?>
```

Lo que necesito es que al ejecutar el código se lea el `txt` y haga/actualice un `array($datos)` de manera que:

- Cada línea del `txt` corresponde a un nuevo registro en el array `$datos(id,tipo,contador)`.
- Si la `id` ya existe en el `array` en lugar de crear un nuevo registro incremente la clave `contador` de esta `id` en `+1`.

He probado `explode` y `in-array` pero la verdad que no consigo verificar si existe la `id` y que me funcione pues en el `txt` pueden venir más de 1000 ids y con `explode` la cosa no va.

Seguramente debe haber otra manera de hacerlo.
Si pueden darme una mano por favor, estoy estancado y sobresaturado de buscar info en manuales y no me entero.
Saludos

Comment: En primer lugar , ¿de que lenguaje estamos hablando? ¿ tiene que ser obligatoriamente arrays? No olvides compartir tu código en formato texto para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El código es en php, el código que tengo no es válido pero te lo copio arriba.

Comment: Puse el código. No tiene porque ser arrays si existe otra manera de hacerlo. Digo array porque necesito guardar los valores y que cada vez que lea el archivo los actualice.

Comment: no tengo ni idea de php , pero por ejemplo en C#/java existen los diccionarios o hashmaps en donde guardas clave y valor . Las claves son unicas y no se repiten entonces lo que haces es aumentar el valor

Comment: Lo suyo es php porque el resto del código lo tengo en php. Aunque en java no lo he pensado. Si me quieres poner un ejemplo de código puedo probarlo.

Comment: La pregunta es confusa. ¿Quieres actualizar un array a partir de otro array? ¿Es eso? Muestra cómo están constituidos ambos arrays y explica con más claridad (entiéndase con más sencillez)  lo que hay que hacer. Te pierdes demasiado en las explicaciones.

Comment: El .txt tiene la misma sintaxis que un .csv. Lo que tienes que hacer es leer el fichero linea a linea y en cada linea hacer un explode de la información. Luego lo insertas en un array con keys ```arrau(key => valor,.....)``` de esa forma luego compruebas si existe la key haciendo un ```array_key_exists
($key, $array)``` Si existe le estableces +1. Sino lo insertas. Nota: para hacer un foreach con las keys es ```foreach($array as $key => $valor)```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda compañeros!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, lo que buscas hacer es `parsear` el contenido en el archivo `txt`, guardarlo en un arreglo con formato `[id, tipo, contador]` y si en el arreglo ya existe un registro con el mismo `id`, debemos incrementar el `contador`.

Para llevar esto a cabo puedes hacerlo así:

```
<?php

// Matriz asociativa para mapear id y posición
$hash = [];
// Arreglo de resultados
$datos = [];

// Obtenemos un arreglo con las líneas del archivo
$lineas = file('C:\users.txt');
foreach ($lineas as $linea) {

    // Extraemos los datos de la línea
    list($id, $tipo, $contador) = explode('|', trim($linea));

    // Si aún no hemos agregado el id al hash
    if (!isset($hash[$id])) {
        // Guardamos en el hash el id y la posicion en el arreglo de datos
        $hash[$id] = count($datos);

        // Guardamos el id en el arreglo de datos
        $datos[] = [
            'id'=>$id,
            'tipo'=>$tipo, 
            'contador'=>$contador,
        ];
    } else {
        // Sumamos al contador del id guardado 1
        $datos[$hash[$id]]['contador']++;
    }
}

var_export($datos);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8cdc8e916a72678a3bba3f9287ad44b8fbb362d4)</kbd>

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he probado el código y va perfecto, pero  no es exactamente lo que necesito. Si la id existe no debe crear otro registro nuevo con la id y el contador +1. Si encuentra una id en el array entonces lo que debe hacer es variar la clave [3] (contador) sumando +1 al número que ya había. De paso me he dado cuenta que con esta forma que planteas no hace falta que ponga en el txt el campo contador. De esta manera solo tiene que leer la id si no existe crea el campo y pone contador 1, si existe pues le suma. omg que lio!!

Comment: @MarcVera, actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos el código me funciona perfectamente. Me he dado cuenta que lo tengo mal planteado. Doy por solucionada esta duda.

Comment: Marcos una última cosa, he modificado el código. He añadido código para que me ordene el array por el número de contador y me da error Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array on line 36 y Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or sorting flag that has not already been specified on line 39. Entonces entiendo que $datos no es un array?? Si pudieras darme una última ayudita. Saludos

Comment: @MarcVera, Editar la respuesta para plantear una nueva pregunta no es lo correcto. Lo ideal es que crees una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema que se te ha presentado. PD: `$datos` si es un array, el problema se debe a otra cosa.

Comment: Ok, pensé que sería mejor continuar aquí. Gracias.